# Filtering and Merging Many Large CSV Files

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to filter and merge 300+ 50,000kb(500k lines) csv files and then output them into another csv file. The filtering is done based on one or more of the values in the columns. I've tried to find a couple different examples but nothing that covers filtering, merging/appending, and NOT keeping the data in memory.

for example i would want to merge all records for INV_ITEM_ID 8010.

All the CSV files are in the same format and would need to be filtered the same way.

```
 RUN_DATE   |FORECAST_SET   |INV_ITEM_ID    |FORECAST_DATE  |FORECAST_QTY
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 26-Mar-15  |A              |4162           |11/19/2016     | 100
 26-Mar-15  |A              |8010           |11/19/2016     | 100
 26-Mar-15  |A              |4162           |11/19/2016     | 100
 26-Mar-15  |B              |4162           |11/19/2016     | 100
 26-Mar-15  |B              |4162           |11/19/2016     | 100
 26-Mar-15  |B              |8010           |11/19/2016     | 100
 26-Mar-15  |B              |4162           |11/19/2016     | 100
 26-Mar-15  |B              |8010           |11/19/2016     | 100
```

Comment: can you provide samples of two of the csv files and be more explicit in your explanation of what you want filtered and merged?

Comment: Will the output be just the 3 rows with 8010 on?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav. Yes i would just want to write those three lines to a file. along with similar lines from 300 other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a performance point of view you probably want to avoid `Import-Csv`/`Export-Csv` and go with a [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)/[`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) approach. Something like this:

```
$inputFolder = 'C:\some\folder'
$outputFile  = 'C:\path\to\output.csv'

$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter ($outputFile, $false)

Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File | Where-Object {
  ...  # <-- filtering criteria for selecting input files go here
} | ForEach-Object {
  $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader ($_.FullName)
  if (-not $headerWritten) {
    # copy header line to output file once
    $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine())
    $headerWritten = $true
  } else {
    # discard header line
    $reader.ReadLine()
  }

  while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
    $line   = $reader.ReadLine()
    $fields = $line -split ','
    if (...) {  # <-- filtering criteria for selecting output lines go here
      $writer.WriteLine($line)
    }
  }

  $reader.Close()
  $reader.Dispose()
}

$writer.Close()
$writer.Dispose()
```

Comment: It didn't like the `-file` portion of the below line but i got it to work. thank you ! `Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File | Where-Object `

Comment: @BenjaminB Then you're still using PowerShell v2 and should upgrade. In the meantime you can filter for files by adding `$_.PSIsContainer` to the `Where-Object` condition(s).

Comment: `-not $_.PSIsContainer` I mean.