# Need split to long (1,000,000+ line) CSV files based on column value and rename with value from other column

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I have folder CSV files in the following format:

**file-2017-08-14.csv**

```
Ticker  Price   Date
AAPL    1   2017-08-14
AAPL    2   2017-08-14
AAPL    3   2017-08-14
AAPL    4   2017-08-14
MSFT    5   2017-08-14
MSFT    6   2017-08-14
MSFT    7   2017-08-14
GOOG    8   2017-08-14
GOOG    9   2017-08-14
...
```

**file-2017-08-13.csv**

```
Ticker  Price   Date
AAPL    1   2017-08-13
AAPL    2   2017-08-13
AAPL    3   2017-08-13
AAPL    4   2017-08-13
MSFT    5   2017-08-13
MSFT    6   2017-08-13
MSFT    7   2017-08-13
GOOG    8   2017-08-13
GOOG    9   2017-08-13
...
```

and so on. I need to split this into 2X3= 6 subfiles, named accordingly:

**/out/AAPL-2017-08-14.csv**

```
Ticker  Price   Date
AAPL    1   2017-08-14
AAPL    2   2017-08-14
AAPL    3   2017-08-14
AAPL    4   2017-08-14
```

**/out/MSFT-2017-08-14.csv**

```
Ticker  Price   Date
MSFT    5   2017-08-14
MSFT    6   2017-08-14
MSFT    7   2017-08-14
```

**/out/GOOG-2017-08-14.csv**

```
Ticker  Price   Date
GOOG    8   2017-08-14
GOOG    9   2017-08-14
```

**/out/AAPL-2017-08-13.csv**

```
Ticker  Price   Date
AAPL    1   2017-08-13
AAPL    2   2017-08-13
AAPL    3   2017-08-13
AAPL    4   2017-08-13
```

**/out/MSFT-2017-08-13.csv**

```
Ticker  Price   Date
MSFT    5   2017-08-13
MSFT    6   2017-08-13
MSFT    7   2017-08-13
```

**/out/GOOG-2017-08-13.csv**

```
Ticker  Price   Date
GOOG    8   2017-08-13
GOOG    9   2017-08-13
```

I have written a script that can group by ticker and split for one file, but I can't figure out how to do the proper renaming and I don't know how to loop over all of the files in the input folder.

```
Import-Csv file-2017-08-14.csv | Group-Object -Property "Ticker" | Foreach-Object {
    $path = $_.Name + ".csv";
    $_.Group | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to confirm, you need to split each date-specific CSV file into one CSV file per Ticker per date?

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution?  Do you need a script to support an arbitrary number of files across an arbitrary number of dates with an arbitrary set of tickers?  Or do you need to do this just once to split 2 files into 6?  If it's the latter, I'd just write it dead simple in 8 lines of code that brute force it.  If it's the former, well, that's much more complicated.

Comment: General solution, as I will have hundreds of CSV files to split

Comment: One csv file, per ticker, per date.

Comment: `Group-Object` requires reading the entire file into memory. You should avoid that for large files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method 1

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.csv' -File -Force `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FullName' `
    | Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" `
    | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $outputFilePath = "out\{0}-{1}.csv" -f $_.Ticker, $_.Date;

        $_ | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation;
    };
```

The lines above perform the following:

- `Get-ChildItem` retrieves `.csv` files from the current directory (not including child directories)
- The result of `Get-ChildItem` will be [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) instances, but we want to pass `string` instances representing the file paths to `Import-Csv`, so we use `Select-Object` to pass only the `FullName` property down the pipeline
- `Import-Csv` reads the CSV file(s) specified in the pipeline and passes each record down the pipeline
- Inside of `ForEach-Object`, the `$_` variable holds each CSV record.  We build the output path appropriate for that record using its `Ticker` and `Date` properties (the latter of which is a `string` and not a [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime), so no [formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) necessary).  We then pass the record to `Export-Csv`, having it append the new row to the file at `$outputPath`.

While this code is short and simple, opening and appending to each output file once per input record is very slow, especially for a million lines, though memory usage is minimal because only one record is in memory at any given time.

### Method 2

We can improve the code by only appending to each output file after every 1,000 records (or whatever value you like) instead of every record.  A `HashTable` stores the pending records for each output file, and the pending records are flushed when a given output file has exceeded the pending record limit or there are no more records to be read (end of the input files):

```
$pendingRecordsByFilePath = @{};
$maxPendingRecordsPerFilePath = 1000;

Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.csv' -File -Force `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FullName' `
    | Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" `
    | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $outputFilePath = "out\{0}-{1}.csv" -f $_.Ticker, $_.Date;
        $pendingRecords = $pendingRecordsByFilePath[$outputFilePath];

        if ($pendingRecords -eq $null)
        {
            # This is the first time we're encountering this output file; create a new array
            $pendingRecords = @();
        }
        elseif ($pendingRecords.Length -ge $maxPendingRecordsPerFilePath)
        {
            # Flush all pending records for this output file
            $pendingRecords `
                | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation;
            $pendingRecords = @();
        }

        $pendingRecords += $_;
        $pendingRecordsByFilePath[$outputFilePath] = $pendingRecords;
    };

# No more input records to be read; flush all pending records for each output file
foreach ($outputFilePath in $pendingRecordsByFilePath.Keys)
{
    $pendingRecordsByFilePath[$outputFilePath] `
        | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation;
}
```

### Method 3

We can improve this even further by using a [`List<object>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) instead of an array to store pending records to write.  By setting the capacity of the list upon creation to `$maxPendingRecordsPerFileName` this will eliminate the overhead of expanding those arrays every time another record is added.

```
$pendingRecordsByFilePath = @{};
$maxPendingRecordsPerFilePath = 1000;

Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.csv' -File -Force `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FullName' `
    | Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" `
    | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $outputFilePath = "out\{0}-{1}.csv" -f $_.Ticker, $_.Date;
        $pendingRecords = $pendingRecordsByFilePath[$outputFilePath];

        if ($pendingRecords -eq $null)
        {
            # This is the first time we're encountering this output file; create a new list
            $pendingRecords = New-Object `
                -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]' `
                -ArgumentList (,$maxPendingRecordsPerFilePath);
            $pendingRecordsByFilePath[$outputFilePath] = $pendingRecords;
        }
        elseif ($pendingRecords.Count -ge $maxPendingRecordsPerFilePath)
        {
            # Flush all pending records for this output file
            $pendingRecords `
                | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation;
            $pendingRecords.Clear();
        }
        $pendingRecords.Add($_);
    };

# No more input records to be read; flush all pending records for each output file
foreach ($outputFilePath in $pendingRecordsByFilePath.Keys)
{
    $pendingRecordsByFilePath[$outputFilePath] `
        | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation;
}
```

### Method 4a

We can eliminate the need for buffering records/lines for output and constantly opening/appending the output files if we use the [`StreamWriter` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter).  We'll create one `StreamWriter` per output file and leave them open until we're finished.  A `try`/`finally` block is necessary to ensure they get closed properly.  I use `ConvertTo-Csv` to generate the output, which always includes a header line whether we need it or not, so there is logic to ensure we only write the header when the file is first opened.

```
$truncateExistingOutputFiles = $true;
$outputFileWritersByPath = @{};

try
{
    Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.csv' -File -Force `
        | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FullName' `
        | Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" `
        | ForEach-Object -Process {
            $outputFilePath = Join-Path -Path (Get-Location) -ChildPath ('out\{0}-{1}.csv' -f $_.Ticker, $_.Date);
            $outputFileWriter = $outputFileWritersByPath[$outputFilePath];
            $outputLines = $_ | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation;

            if ($outputFileWriter -eq $null)
            {
                # This is the first time we're encountering this output file; create a new StreamWriter
                $outputFileWriter = New-Object `
                    -TypeName 'System.IO.StreamWriter' `
                    -ArgumentList ($outputFilePath, -not $truncateExistingOutputFiles, [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII);

                $outputFileWritersByPath[$outputFilePath] = $outputFileWriter;

                # Write the header line
                $outputFileWriter.WriteLine($outputLines[0]);
            }

            # Write the data line
            $outputFileWriter.WriteLine($outputLines[1]);
        };
}
finally
{
    foreach ($writer in $outputFileWritersByPath.Values)
    {
        $writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, this caused a performance change of 175%...*slower*.  I'll nail down why that is as I further revise this code.

### Method 4b

My first thought to address the performance drop was to reintroduce output buffering; basically, combine method 3 and 4a.  Equally surprising, this only further hurt performance.  My only guess as to why is that since the `StreamWriter` does its own character buffering it makes doing our own buffering unnecessary.  In fact, I tested values for `maxPendingRecordsPerFilePath` in powers of 10 from 10 to 100,000 and the overall performance difference those two extremes was a mere 5 seconds.  Thus, our own buffering isn't really helping anything, and the tiny overhead of managing the `List` adds up to an additional 30 seconds run time over a million iterations.  So, let's scrap the buffering.

### Method 4c

Instead of using `ConvertTo-Csv` to out a 2-element array of `string`s (a header line and a data line), let's build this two lines ourselves using `string` formatting.

### Method 4d

On every iteration of `ForEach-Object` we need to build the output file path because it's based on the input objects `Ticker` and `Date` properties.  We pass an absolute path when constructing the `StreamWriter` because PowerShell has a different notion of the "current directory" (from which relative paths would be based) than a typical .NET application.  We've been calling `Get-Location` to build this absolute path on every iteration, which isn't necessary because that path doesn't change.  So, let's move the call to `Get-Location` outside of `ForEach-Object`.

### Method 4e

Instead of using `Join-Path` to build our output file path, let's try .NET's [`Path.Combine` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_).

### Method 4f

Instead of using `Join-Path` to build our output file path, let's try the less platform-agnostic `string` interpolation (`$outputFilePath = "$outputDirectoryPath\$outputFileName";`).

Combining the changes from methods **4a**, **4c**, **4d**, and **4e** we get this final code:

```
$truncateExistingOutputFiles = $true;
$outputDirectoryPath = Join-Path -Path (Get-Location) -ChildPath 'out';
$outputFileWritersByPath = @{};

try
{
    Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.csv' -File -Force `
        | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FullName' `
        | Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" `
        | ForEach-Object -Process {
            $outputFileName = '{0}-{1}.csv' -f $_.Ticker, $_.Date;
            $outputFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($outputDirectoryPath, $outputFileName);
            $outputFileWriter = $outputFileWritersByPath[$outputFilePath];

            if ($outputFileWriter -eq $null)
            {
                # This is the first time we're encountering this output file; create a new StreamWriter
                $outputFileWriter = New-Object `
                        -TypeName 'System.IO.StreamWriter' `
                        -ArgumentList ($outputFilePath, -not $truncateExistingOutputFiles, [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII);

                $outputFileWritersByPath[$outputFilePath] = $outputFileWriter;

                # Write the header line
                $outputFileWriter.WriteLine('"Ticker","Price","Date"');
            }

            # Write the data line
            $outputFileWriter.WriteLine("""$($_.Ticker)"",""$($_.Price)"",""$($_.Date)""");
        };
}
finally
{
    foreach ($writer in $outputFileWritersByPath.Values)
    {
        $writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Here are my benchmarks for each method averaged over three runs each against a million line CSV.  This was performed on a Core i7 860 @ 2.8 GHz with TurboBoost disabled running 64-bit PowerShell v5.1 on Windows 10 Pro v1703:

```
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| Method |     Path handling    |     Line building    | File writing |   Output buffering  |  Execution time |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    1   |       Relative       |      Export-Csv      |  Export-Csv  |          No         | 2,178.5 seconds |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    2   |       Relative       |      Export-Csv      |  Export-Csv  | 1,000-element array |   222.9 seconds |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    3   |       Relative       |      Export-Csv      |  Export-Csv  |  1,000-element List |   154.2 seconds |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|   4a   |       Join-Path      |     ConvertTo-Csv    | StreamWriter |          No         |   425.0 seconds |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|   4b   |       Join-Path      |     ConvertTo-Csv    | StreamWriter |  1,000-element List |   456.1 seconds |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|   4c   |       Join-Path      | String interpolation | StreamWriter |          No         |   302.5 seconds |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|   4d   |       Join-Path      | String interpolation | StreamWriter |          No         |   225.1 seconds |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|   4e   | [IO.Path]::Combine() | String interpolation | StreamWriter |          No         |    78.0 seconds |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|   4f   | String interpolation | String interpolation | StreamWriter |          No         |    77.7 seconds |
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Key takeaways:

- When used with `Export-Csv`, output buffering (1 → 2 and 1 → 3) provides a massive performance improvement.
- When used with `StreamWriter`s, output buffering (4a → 4b) is not helpful and actually causes a small performance hit.
- Eliminating `ConvertTo-Csv` (4a → 4c) reduced execution time by a third (153.6 seconds).
- Method 4a is so much slower than the buffered `Export-Csv` methods because it introduced the use of `Get-Location` and `Join-Path`.  Either these cmdlets invole a lot more processing behind the scenes than meets the eye, or invoking cmdlets is slow in general (when done a million times, of course).

  - Moving `Get-Location` outside of `ForEach-Object` (4c → 4d) reduced execution time by a quarter (77.4 seconds).
  - Using `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()` instead of `Join-Path` (4d → 4e) reduced execution time by two-thirds (147.1 seconds).
- Script optimization is fun and educational!

Comment: Thank you kind sir. Worked like a charm for my toy files. It does take quite some time for the actual files however, so I am leaving this open for now.

Comment: Yes, it is slow.  I have an improved version in the works.  Just testing it now.

Comment: @Taylor If performance is an issue you may want to consider using a [`StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` combination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34616599/1630171). Beware, though, that with that approach you will need to handle a lot of things yourself that `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` normally would do for you.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Ha, that's the solution I'm working on right now.  Curious how much time will be saved by opening each output file exactly one.

Comment: I would expect the difference to be significant even if you stick with appending to the files.

Comment: I have added a solution utilizing the `StreamWriter` class.  I am running benchmarks on my four solutions now and will update my answer in a few hours with the results.

Comment: Code works beautifully. Thank you so much! Marking as solved. One minor last question - I am running into problems with how the data is formatted in my date column. The data is more like "2017-08-15 10:15:00" in my actual files, so I am running into issues with the timestamp portion and need to truncate the Date column before the time. Any ideas?

Comment: That adds a new wrinkle because all my code above is column/property-agnostic and let's `Export-Csv`/`ConvertTo-Csv` copy the values over, whereas your addendum requires transforming one of the columns. This is untested, but you could do something like `$_ | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty 'Date' -Property '*', @{ Name = 'Date'; Expression = { ([DateTime] $_.Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'); }; } | Export-Csv` to parse and reformat only the `Date` property. Alternatively, split it on the space character and take only the first element: `$_.Date -split ' ', 2 | Select-Object -First 1`.

Comment: I replaced $_Date with  ($_.Date.substring(0,10)) and it took care of it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Taylor Curiosity got the best of me as to why my `StreamWriter` method performed so much slower than `Export-Csv` with `List` buffering.  I have updated my answer with my findings, including code that is twice as fast!